# What is the behaviour of producer poll?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am slightly confused, perhaps surprised, by the behaviour of `producer.poll(timeout)`. Or at least by the behaviour I am observing.

I expected (perhaps incorrectly) that the behaviour would be similar to `consumer.poll(timeout)`.

- When `consumer.poll(timeout)` is called, if there are no pending messages to consume, the function will block for `timeout` before returning some value indicating no message. (In Python this is a `None`.)
- If there are pending messages, then `consumer.poll(timeout)` returns the next pending message, provided that `timeout` is long enough for the required work to fetch this message to be completed. (It doesn't typically work very well if `timeout` is set to a value less than 1 second, especially on "regular" networks. (In other words, it might be ok to have a very short poll time on high-performance datacenter networks, but across regular local networks or the www it typically needs to be some value high enough to compensate for the typical latencies seen.)

In contrast, this is the behaviour I see with `producer.poll(timeout)`.

- If there are no pending messages in the producer buffer, then this function waits for `timeout` before returning. It **does not** return immediatly if there are no messages in the producer buffer to dispatch. **I find this behaviour surprising. I would have expected it to return immediatly if there are no pending messages.**
- If there are pending messages in the producer buffer, then `producer.poll(timeout)` waits for at most `timeout`. If the buffer is fully purged of pending messages during `timeout` then it will return early. (I have tested this.) If there are a large number of messages to dispatch, `poll(timeout)` will return after `timeout` if there are still more messages in the buffer. This is the expected behaviour. In order to "flush" the buffer completely, a call to `flush` with no timeout is required, or `producer.poll(timeout)` can be called manually with a relatively short `timeout` value, until no messages remain. (This is how I am doing it, and I use the producer callback functions to count the number of delivered messages.)

What is the expected behaviour of `producer.poll(timeout)`.

- If there are no messages to send, should it really be waiting for `timeout` for seemingly no reason? Why does it behave this way?
- If there are messages to send, it does not wait for `timeout` if the buffer can be emptied in less than `timeout`. For example, if `timeout` is set to 10 seconds, and the buffer empties after 1 second, then it does not wait for the remaining 9 seconds before returning.

So why the seemingly inconsistent behaviour?